# Can HTML5 access native components

Tags: android, html

I have a question. Can an HTML5 page interact with native components in android?

What i am trying to achieve is that on a HTML5 page that displays a list of content. i want to create a notification that some content has arrived.?

Im guessing, a way to do this is to use a webview and display my HTML5 content there but how to do get callback from the webview so that i can notify a user that some content has arrived via notifications bar that can be access using native android coding?

I already know how to create notifications on android and how to create a webview, i just need to find a way to send data from html5 page to a android component and possibly vice versa.

Can this be achievable or too ambitious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this via a JavaScript Interface. Via this the JavaScript can call functions defined in the interface you attach.

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

In your `Activity`:

```
WebAppInterface mInterface;

public void onCreate() {
    mInterface = new WebAppInterface(this);
    mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(mInterface, "MyAndroidInterface")
}
```

Now define an object where the calls will go to:

```
public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Now in `Javascript` you can do:

```
MyAndroidInterface.showToast("hello world");
```

The way back (from `native` to `Javascript`) you can do via `Javascript injection`.
Define function in `Javascript`:

```
function helloBack(param) {
}
```

Now you can call `mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:helloBack(hi);");`

Comment: excellent. just what i am looking for. With this i can send Intents, access services etc using this interface?

Comment: Yes, make sure you component has the Context which is required for the Intent sending.